# Laravel4 Blade template issue: extends method is printed as a string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, templating, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel4, so I was learning from the documentation.
It seems everything is all correct, but the extends method literally displays its code on my web browser. I don't know hwy..

This is the layout file (base.blade.php under layouts directory)

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/base.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <!-- You can provide some default content -->
    @section('head')
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    @show
</head>
<body>
    @yield('body')
</body>
</html>
```

and home.blade.php.

```
<!-- app/views/home.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.base')

@section('body')
    <h1>Hurray!</h1>
    <p>We have a template!</p>
@stop
```

and my routing configuration is like below..

```
Route::get('/', 
  function()
  {
    return View::make('home');
  }
);
```

Now when you access to the URL, it displays just a string!

```
@extends('layouts.base')
```

I have been googling for a hour or so! still could not fix it...
What's wrong with them? :(

- I checked common mistakes below
- possible type
- incorrect path
- incorrect method name
- missing appending 'blade' on the file name

BUT STILL CAN'T FIND THE PROBLEM. :(

Comment: My friend just told me this works on his framework weirdly.. I don't know why it does not work to mine. -_-..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any space in the template above @extends at all no comments or whitespace

Answer (score 2):

Remove 
`<!-- app/views/home.blade.php -->` from `home.blade.php`

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('body')
    <h1>Hurray!</h1>
    <p>We have a template!</p>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities are that you have printed `@extends('layouts.base')` twice in the page. Please have a look.